# "Дешево и сердито"

Tags: фразеология

А почему говорят "дешево и сердито"? Почему — сердито?

Answer (score 4):

Всё дело в том, что оказалось забыто старое значение наречия «сердито». Раньше «сердитый» среди других имело также значение «стОящий, хороший». (Тут надо вспомнить, что прилагательное «сердитый» образовано от «сърдъ» - «сердце»).
Это значение ярко проявлялось в обороте «*сердитая цена*», сегодня вышедшем из употребления. К примеру, у Николая Лескова находим такие строки: *«У графини теперь… страстное желание иметь пару сереньких лошадок с колясочкой, хотя не очень сердитой цены»*.
Отсюда в виде каламбура возникло выражение «и дёшево и сердито». Ведь буквально оно значит «и дёшево, и дорого», но дорого не по цене, а по качеству. Несомненно свою роль при этом сыграло желание поспорить с известной пословицей «дорого, да мило; дешево да гнило».

Поскольку самые ранние ссылки на это выражение связаны со спиртными напитками (ср.: у Салтыкова-Щедрина в ”Помпадурах“: ”Над дверьми нахально красуется вывеска: ”И дешево и сердито“), надо думать, что первоначально оно употреблялось относительно питейных заведений где за недорого можно было напиться самогоном сердито (т.е. до состояния буйства). Потом значение фразы затерялось и она стала употребляться в отношении относительно недорогих, но отвечающих своему назначению вещей.

Comment: "Сердитая цена" не вышло из употребления. Сам неоднократно его слышал.
Даже не знаю, можно ли сказать, что оно переомыслилось... 
Суть-то осталась та же. Высокая цена - сердитая. В каком угодно смысле. И "злая" и "подходить страшно". Все вполне в духе исходного значения. 

Answer (score 0):

Дёшево  и  сердито.  Доля  иронии  здесь тоже  есть.  Но,  в  общем,  это  удачная  покупка.  И  не  дорого,  и  хорошо.  Особенно,  если  денег  мало.

Answer (score 0):

Дешево и сердито. Сердито значит строго, без дополнительных затрат на сервисное обслуживание.

Comment: Ответ спорный по содержанию и неполный по форме — не подкреплен никакими ссылками или логически стройными рассуждениями автора.

Answer (score 0):

В "дёшево и сердито" ставил бы запятую, т. к. оценка двунаправленная — и то, и другое по положительной шкале (ни противопоставления, ни иронии здесь нет) — по стоимости и исполнению: разумному, с глубоким пониманием. О смысле наречия *сердито* надо судить по однокоренному существительному *сердце*:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, я не могу подтвердить свой ответ ссылкой на авторитетные источники, но насколько я помню, выражение "дешево и сердито" изначально применялось в питейных заведениях и означало, что в ассортименте есть **дешевый, но крепкий (высокоградусный) алкоголь**.

Answer (score 0):

[Словарь Ушакова](https://www.efremova.info/word/serdito.html#.W_bNEHkUlZQ):

> Значение слова сердито
>   Ударение: серди́то
>   нареч.
>   1.С раздражением, гневом, злобой. 
>   2.Устрашающе.
>   3.перен. разг. Очень сильно.
>
> Похожие слова
>   • сердитая — Женский род к существительному: сердитый 
>   • сердитый — Тот, кто сердится на кого-л., что-л., испытывает чувство гнева, раздражения. 1) а) Сердящийся на кого-л., что-л., испытывающий чувство гнева, раздражения (о человеке). 2) а) перен. разг. Сильный в своем проявлении; свирепый, лютый (о морозе

То, что нас интересует — сильный в своем проявлении. "Дешево и сильно в своем проявлении", а дальше каждый понимает как хочет: дешево и качественно, дешево и сильно пьянит т. п. Самые спорные трактовки: дешево и очень плохо, дешево и очень дорого.

Answer (score -1):

Да, выходит, что "сердито" означает "качественно, ст**o**ит тех денег, что просят за товар"

Comment: Постарайтесь давать более обоснованную версию, а не просто соглашаться с предыдущими.

Answer (score -2):

Может я не до конца понял автора текста из ответа olsa, тогда заранее извиняюсь.
Но как-то сложновато все выходит.

У Виноградова этой версии (вывод значения из сердито = хорошо) нет, он говорит только о том, что изначально оно относилось к водке. "Сердито" могло означать что-то наподобие нынешнего "сердечно", но оно никак не влезает в представление о ценах. Да и время существования этого значения вызывает сомнения. Будь оно таким во времена Лескова, наверняка где-либо еще было зафиксировано.

Короче, современное значение "дешево и(но) сердито" вполне однозначно толкуется как намек на качество обслуживания. Точно так же это понятно по отношению к водке. Дешевая, но сердитая (плохая, не радующая) водка - это тоже понятно. 
Явялется ли это значение переосмыслением или исходным - сказать наверняка не берусь, но склоняюмь к последнему, т.е. к тому, что при возникновении оно уже значило "дешево, но плохо".

Comment: Так "сердито" - не о ценах, о качестве. Не знаю, может раньше "сердито" здесь и означало "плохо", сейчас такого смысла не чувствуется. Наоборот, выражение употребляется в положительном смысле. Здесь я согласна с Вики (или Вики со мной ;-)) )

Comment: Поддерживаю мысль о том, что в современном звучании фраза "дешево, но сердито" употребляется в смысле "дешево(просто), но хорошо(качественно)

Comment: >Так "сердито" - не о ценах, о качестве.

О качестве чего? Обслуживания?
Чот с этой темой у меня какое-то помутнение прямо.

DocentI, сформулируете явно, как бы этот положительный смыл звучал? "недорого и (но) хорошо" - уменя что-то никак не стыкуется.
Что вообще такое "хорошая" цена у Лескова тогда значит? 

>Поддерживаю мысль о том, что в современном звучании фраза "дешево, но сердито" 

Я по нацкорпусу посмотрел, "но сердито", там вообще нет. "И сердито" в современных вариантах - ну никак не "хорошо". Достопну, терпимо, приемлемо - ну это еще можно вывести.

Comment: Про Лескова не знаю, у него мог быть другой смысл. У меня "дешево и сердито" вообще не ассоциируется с процессом покупки, скорее, с качеством предмета (или даже нематериального объекта). Мой "перевод": нечто, получаемое без больших усилий, но вполне хорошее (последнее, правда, с некоторой иронией, то есть объект не идеальный, но приемлемый)  
Вы, правде, не любите, когда говорят "мне кажется". Но ведь язык и складывается из привычек его носителей, которые потом кодифицируются учеными.

Comment: Цитата из Лескоаа - в ответе olsa. На ней строится всё обоснование "сердитой цены".
Прмемлемый - да. Приемлемая цена (лошадок) - это понимаемо.
Вне всязи с покупкой и сферой обслуживания представить использование выражения не могу в принципе. Если только в совсем уж переносном значении типа "просто и нетрудно"... Здесь что-то не то со смыслом. Ладно, спишем на мою серость. Спасибо.